# Relationship Between Velocity at Lowest Position and Gravitational Acceleration in Pendulum Motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, string, centripetal-force

To my knowledge there are two methods of finding this relationship. One with the centripetal force and the other with conservation of energy. I've left my work in the image below.

[image: The formula above was found using centripetal force. The formula below was found using conservation of mechanical energy]

The problem here is that both of them give the complete opposite results. My question is, which of the two are correct and why is the other one wrong?

Any and all answers are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I think you're solving two different problems. The first one sets a condition for a tightness $T$ which is sufficient in order for the pendulum to be in circular motion of uniform velocity. The second is the condition that all gravitational potential energy of the pendulum gets converted into kinetic energy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, initially I did not understand what you were trying to do. The issue is that $T$ is not a constant. So $T$ is increasing as well, it increases with $g$ by more than the $-mg$ decreases, leading to a net increase under the radical and overall. If you think about it, this makes sense because $T$ includes both gravity and centripetal force.

In order to use the first method to find $v$, you would have to substitute $T$ out of the equation from elsewhere. This is not a convenient way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Both equations are correct and if you combine them you will see the reason for your uncertainty.

$v = \sqrt{2gh} =\sqrt{\frac{(T-mg)r}{m}} \Rightarrow T=mg\left ( \frac {2h}{r}+1\right)$

Keeping $h$ and $r$ constant, if $g$ is increased then so is $T$ which means that the tension is not constant but depends on the gravitational field strength.

Comment: I think that's assuming the question is about finding the tension $T$ to satisfy the circular motion acceleration criteria $a=v^2/r$, it's not clear from the OP if that's what he is asked to do...

Comment: @Amit The OP said his results are contradictory.  I have shown that they are not if tension is not assumed to be constant.

Comment: correct. I only point out that the second result is sufficient to solve the problem as it is phrased in OP title